# Put two values in one Arraylist, then read them in one for loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Is it possible to read the value of **valueAfterMovingAverage** and the value of **FrontalSpeed** from my arraylist list during the for loop? The technical issue is in my for loop I guess. It is reading only the size of valueAfterMovingAverage but not the values of FrontalSpeed that are stored in list array.

So the for loop reads only the value of the first array.
**I should highlight** that the two value's size (I mean the two variable array) aren't the same. How can I write their (into my text file) values in my for loop. The current results in my text file have the second value repeated and that is false. It has to be changed based on the reading from sensor accelerometer.

```
float valueAfterMovingAverage;
double TotalAccelerate;
ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
// The light sensor returns a single value.
// Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
if (isListening) {
    double xx = event.values[0];
    double yy = event.values[1];
    double zz = event.values[2];
    TotalAccelerate = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            + Math.pow(yy, 2)
            + Math.pow(zz, 2)));
    Log.i(DEBUG, "Accelerometer = " + TotalAccelerate);
    FrontalSpeed = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            + Math.pow(zz, 2)));

    Log.i(DEBUG, "list values " + listPeaks);
    MovingAverage ma = new MovingAverage(2);
    ma.newNum(TotalAccelerate);
    valueAfterMovingAverage = (float) ma.getAvg();
    sensorText.setText(String.valueOf(valueAfterMovingAverage));
    Log.i(DEBUG, "Moving avg:  " + valueAfterMovingAverage);
      list.add(valueAfterMovingAverage);
      list.add(FrontalSpeed);
      Log.i(DEBUG,"Size of List: "+ list.size());

  }

}

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ...
   ...


OnStore = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onStore);
OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (OnStore.isChecked()) {
            //
            // set listening flag to true
            //
            isListening = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (!OnStore.isChecked()) { //
            // set listening flag to false
            //
            isListening = false;

            try {
                for (double valueFromList : list) {
                    String space = "\n";
                    byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                    fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                    String finalData;

                    finalData = String.valueOf(valueFromList);

                    String line = finalData + " " + FrontalSpeed + "\n";
                    Log.i(DEBUG, "speed: " + FrontalSpeed);
                    fileOutputStream.write(line.getBytes());

                    Log.i(DEBUG, "ans: " + finalData);

                }
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with two separate Arrayslist's. One for holding the amount of valueAfterMovingAverage and another for FrontalSpeed. Just a suggestion.

Comment: You can't do that. This is not the purpose.